# Stop eclipse adding the @Overide annotation

Tags: eclipse, java, j2mepolish

I am using J2ME Polish, compiling for J2ME MIDP 2.1 and using eclipse as my editor. I have been playing around with the Formatter and Code Clean settings for my project to improve code quality. Not matter, how many settings I tweak I cannot get eclipse to stop adding "@Override":

```
@Override
public void someFunc(String parameters) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

How can I stop eclipse adding "@Override" when I click add un-implemented methods?

Edit: I should let others know that J2ME has no annotations.

Comment: What's wrong with having `@Override`? I've found it to be useful.

Comment: Why do you want to have that removed?

Comment: I am compiling for J2ME. It does not have annotations, it uses a smaller VM which has less functionality (e.g. no generics, collections, iterators) and less classes available than the full SE SDK.

Comment: Shouldn't your target jre take care of this?  If your target is J2ME, then it should not even have the option to set something that is not available.

Comment: I am using J2ME Polish which is framework built on top of J2ME. Polish unfortunately does not integrate well with eclipse, I want to use it as my editor and use ant scripts to do the compliation and other hard work. I believe there will be a J2MEPolish plugin for eclipse at some point.

Comment: `it uses a smaller VM which has less functionality` I think you're mistaken. `Override` is a source annotation, not runtime. Whether or not the compiler you're using supports annotations or not, the normal JavaSE compiler discards this annotation. This annotation is not present at runtime (i.e. the JVM won't have any knowledge of it). Just to clear up that language a bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure why you want to disable it but here's how you can do it.

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style
```

and uncheck Add '@Override' annotation for new overriding methods.

[image]

Comment: Wow - high quality answer, especially the nice screenshot :)

Comment: My gosh you people are quick! Thanks, I am a bit new to eclipse and now feel embrassed that I missed that. When I try to save these settings I get an Exception, which is not so greate. See - Error: Exception occurred while saving project preferences: /substate_wallet/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs.
Exception occurred while saving project preferences: /substate_wallet/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs.

Comment: @Graham I'm not sure about that exception but see if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954248/cant-save-project-preferences-in-eclipse

Comment: Cool, the quick fix was to delete the files and add the project to eclipse again. Again thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
Java > Editor > Save Actions > Missing Code (Tab)
```

You can tell java not to add the `@Override` annotation (this is only if it is missing when you save a file), I'm not sure about when adding unimplemented methods. I would have to ask why you would want this, `@Override` only adds extra useful information.