# Eclipse Code Assist Not Work In Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, content-assist

i've already selected Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist for all types.
but i couldn't save the settings. when i restart eclipse it will reset to defaults.i.e. untick Java Type Proposal and others.

i've tested this in 
eclipse  3.7.2,
eclipse 4.2.1,
eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk

My Java version 1.6.0_38

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have some potential causes for Eclipse settings not being saved properly in "[Can't save project preferences in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954248/cant-save-project-preferences-in-eclipse)".
[This thread](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-printview-t-28216-start-0.html) warns again installation of Eclipse done as an Administrator (even though in the end, the actual cause was a faulty Windows(!) installation).

But the safest path would be to create a *new* workspace and see if the issue persists ie, can you save your settings and preferences in that new workspace).

Comment: i've investigate this further and found everytime i'm restarting eclipse org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs add following entry.

content_assist_disabled_computers=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaNoTypeProposalCategory\u0000org.eclipse.jdt.ui.textProposalCategory\u0000org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaTypeProposalCategory\u0000

Comment: @user1920633 do you see the same issue with a "naked" Eclipse (without plugins)? As in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310761, where Mylyn prevented that settings?

Comment: my eclipse 3.7.2 is a "naked" eclipse. when i create a simple JAVA project,the entry content_assist_disabled_computers=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaNoTypeProposalCategory\‌​u00000org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaTypeProp‌​osalCategory\u0000 added to org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs. then i've changed those in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist. prefs file updated correctly. still conent assist not working. after restarting eclipse and goto Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist those entries has been added automatically.